# How does scaling this sin wave work?

Tags: scaling

So I have to scale sin from

-1 to 1

to

0 to 255.

I added one to sin then multiplied it by 255/2.

It works, but isn't this is a completely different point on the graph because of the addition of one?

Comment: A bit unclear - what do you mean by "different point on the graph"?

Comment: Like if you graphed sin(x) and sin(x) + 1 they are different